# I need contacts to help me

Tags: complex-analysis

Are there groups maybe here that will read a particular mathematics text at a certain pace and discuss the more difficult pages? I am struggling with Visual Complex Functions - by Wegert. Great if there was people who are reading this or have done that I could turn too for help.

Comment: Although this question refers to a specific text, its application to *texts in general* makes it of interest to a wider community.